# How to remove the numbering/counter of subfigure with the subfigure package?

Tags: numbering, subfig

How do I modify this code to remove the numbering of subfigure with the ***subfigure*** package? But even the numbering has been removed, I can still refer to them in text.

```
\usepackage[]{subfigure}

      \begin{figure*}[]
        \subfigure[SubCaption-1]
         {          
          \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{fig-1.png}
         }          
        \subfigure[SubCaption-2]
         {          
          \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{fig-2.png}
         }          
        \caption{Caption}  
      \end{figure*}
```

- Current situation:
  [image]
- The result I want:
  [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Don't use package `subfigure`. It is obsolete and replaced by `subfig` or you may consider `subcaption` .

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

- Package `subfigure` is obsolete. Don't use it! Instead it is defined `subfig`, which instead `\subfigure` define `\subfloat` command with similar functionality.
- Newest and more powerful and versatile package `subcaption` version 1.3 also support `\subfloat`.
- Bear in mind that mention packages are not compatible. I had to be used only one of them.
- Using is simple to define desired sub caption style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
\subfloat[First caption   \label{fig:a}]%
    {\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image}}
\hfil
\subfloat[Second long, long, long, long, long caption \label{fig:b}]%
    {\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image}}
\caption{if needed}
  \label{fig:...}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]